# How to change background color of ListView item?

Tags: android

There is the following method:

```
    @Override
    public void mark() {
        ImageView image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.listItemRepeatingTypeImage);
        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        image.invalidate();
        Log.e("event", "mark");
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        view.invalidate();
    }
```

As you can see, I try to change background color for View and ImageView (view is an item of ListView). This event becomes, but there is no new background. How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is this mark method located?

Comment: Is it important? Because I've got "mark" in Logcat.

Comment: Does the background remain green?

Comment: My background always has got white background (the first state)

Comment: Change the color in th getView method in your Listview adapter, works fine

Comment: It works good in getView(), but I need to change background color after in random moment.

Comment: Try to notify the listView adapter: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this style to your ListView:

```
<style name="List">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#CCCCCC</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

And in your xml layout this:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    style="@style/List"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Why shoud I do it? I don't understand how it can help me